# How to find line where exception occursin javascript in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

ASP.NET MVC4 shoping cart application implements error logging from client browser using

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
    $.post('/Home/Error',
    {
        "errorMsg": errorMsg,
        "url": url,
        "lineNumber": lineNumber,
        "column": column,
        "errorobj": JSON.stringify(errorObj)
    });
```

This logs strange errors about token o :

```
Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

urls and column numbers vary a bit:

```
Line 1 Column 2

Line 1 Column 10 Object {}

Line 1 Column 10 Object {}

Line 1 Column 9 Object {}

Line 1 Column 1 Object {}
```

Line number is 1 always, object is empty.
There are 4 different column numbers:  1,2,9,10

How to find line in javascript which causes this exception ?
Exception occurs in client browser where there is no access. Only way is to 
send information about js code line to browser.

Those pages contain few ajax calls. /Store/Browse contains ajax to add item to cart:

```
   request = $.post('/Store/AddToCart',
        serializedData, function (response) {
            $("#cart-status").text(response.Total);
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
            var xx = $form[0].quantity;
            $($form[0].quantity).css("background-color", "green");
            showMessage(response.Message);
            showFadeOutMessage(response.Message);
        })
           .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert('Error ' + textStatus);
           })
          .always(function () {
              $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
          });
```

It is possible to add lastLine assignments to code like

```
   var lastLine;
   lastLine="request = $.post('/Store/AddToCart";

   request = $.post('/Store/AddToCart',
        serializedData, function (response) {

            lastLine='$("#cart-status").text(response.Total)';
            $("#cart-status").text(response.Total);
            lastLine='$inputs.prop("disabled", false)';
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
            ...
```

and send lastLine value to server in window.onerror but this requires lot of code changes manually.
Is there a better way to find line here error occurs and maybe stack trace also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.onerror is different between IE, Chrome and Firefox. Your code will work in IE. This code will work in IE and chrome.

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
        $.post('/Home/Error',
        {
            "errorMsg": errorMsg,
            "url": url,
            "lineNumber": lineNumber,
            "column": column,
            "errorobj": errorObj ? errorObj.stack : ''
        });
```

In Chrome errorObj contains three properties: name, stack and message- but all are [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). JSON.parse doesn't handle functions and getter is a function.

For example (Chrome only!)

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(errorObj)); // {}
    console.log(errorObj.stack); //SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
                                 //    at Object.parse (native)
                                 //    at foo (http://www.example.com/index.js:8:10)
                                 //    at ...
    console.log(errorObj.message); // Unexpected token o
    console.log(errorObj.name); // SyntaxError
}
```

In IE errorObj it's simple object. But errorObj.stack is clearer.

Firefox does not send errorObj argument. You need wrap the code with try catch (or override JSON.parse and wrap the call with try catch), and send `e.toString()` and `e.stack`. For example:

```
var bckJSON = JSON.parse;
JSON.parse = function () {
    try {
        bckJSON.apply(argumetns};
    } catch (e) {
        // send e.toString() + '\n' + e.stack
    }
}
```

Sorry about previous non-useful answers...

Comment: Thank you. How to make it to work in FireFox also, where to add try/catch ?. How to send all information which is returned in any browser ? According to your answer, chrome returns name also, how to log this ? This shoudl be common requirement, where to find generic onerror handler which logs maximum information from any browser ? I can try to create it according to your answer but I expect that this is already created.

Comment: 1) The name parameter in chrome is include in the stack parameter. This way give you the most data each browser you use. You don't need add a more speciel handle

Comment: 2) If I right, this is JSON.parse that throw this exception. So, override JSON.parse and wrap the call with try/catch.

Comment: `send e.toString() and e.stack` - how to do this? There is no e variable in answer

Comment: `try { //Your code } catch (e) { // e is exeption object }`

Comment: Based on this I created onerror handler and posted it as alternate answer.  Can this handler improved ? If this is OK, I can use it also in overridden JSON.parse and look into logs from users browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The error 'Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o' is occur when you invoke JSON.parse with object.
Probably this code happens -

`JSON.parse({});`

Comment: As you see in the links in question, there is no JSON.parse() used. Some SO answers point that maybe jQuery calls in it internally if response content type declared as json. Application should return proper json. How to find the line where this exception occurs or other way to solve this ?

Comment: What version of Jquery you use?

Comment: I'm using jquery-1.11.1.js file

Answer (score 0):

JQuery, in some cases, use $.parseJSON to convert ajax queries without check if the data is string. I don't know when this happens.

You can workaround in this way:

(Use $.parseJSON because it handle browser without JSON library)

#### JsonParseFix.js

```
function isString(value) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === "[object String]";
}

var bckJSONparse = $.parseJSON;
$.parseJSON = function(text, reviver) {
    if (!isString(text)) {return text};

    bckJSONparse.apply(arguments);
};
```

#### test.js

```
function test(value, message) {
    try {
       $.parseJSON(value);
       console.log('Test succeed: ' + message);
    } catch (e) {
       alert('Test failed: ' + message);
    }
}

test({}, 'Empty object');
test('<', 'UnSupported strings'); // Failed!
```

Angular solve this in a similar way ([angular.fromJson documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1095)).

(Sorry about my english...)

Comment: Thank you. How to use this answer to find line of code where exception occurs in javascript ?

Comment: The exception occurs when ajax requests return. This isn't your code but JQuery code. Call stack will not help you because this happens when async request return. You need understand **why** this happens, not where. If you want to understand why, you need debug jquery code.

Comment: maybe it happens if my application return content-type json in response header but returns invalid json in response body. How to diagnose it ? Should overridden $.parseJSON log text parameter to server of other idea ?

Comment: This help you just to know if the problem is in this function, but not why this happens. I think that you need to; 1) In server save the user browser in logs, maybe the exception occurs in certain browsers. 
If this is the case, reproduce the problem and debug jquery code. 2) If this not help. Replace jquery code with temp version that send logs to server in function done (line 9189 in v1.11.1). You need send the parameters - headers, responses, and s.dataTypes. 
Mostly these parameters determine the type of conversion to occur.

Comment: (I, in that case I would choose to get around the problem I have shown in my reply), but if you choose to study the problem, I'll be happy you share results

Comment: I examined log files after some days of work. user agent string is `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36` this looks like regular chrome browser which I'm using every day without this exception. Exception from overridden `$.parseJSON` is never logged. It seems that exception occurs in other place in code. How to find line which causes exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Elad's andwer and comments I created the following method which returns call stack in IE, Chrome and FireFox:

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
    var stack;
    // Firefox does not send errorObj argument. Wrap the code with try catch 
    // and send e.toString() and e.stack.
    try {
        stack = errorObj ? errorObj.stack : '';
    } catch (e) {
        stack = e.toString() + " stack " + e.stack;
    }

    $.ajax('/api/errorlog?' + $.param({
        errorMsg: errorMsg,
        url: url,
        lineNumber: lineNumber,
        column: column
    }),
      {
          data: JSON.stringify({ stack: stack }),
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: "application/json"
      });
    alert(errorMsg + ' Line ' + lineNumber + ' Column ' + column + '\n\n' + stack);
};
```

Comment: This isn't solution for FF. The expression `errorObj ? errorObj.stack : '';` in FF will return null and not exception.
Even if you throw exception in window.error this willn't help you because the stack trace include only the window.error function. You need wrap the row that throw the exception

Comment: In Firefox stack trace is also returned by this code. Why ? Maybe FireFox returns also errorObj.stack.